# swift collection view: how can I change an image view color of one specific cell?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I need to contact one concrete cell in my collection view **without tapping it**. For example I need to change color of the image in the second cell and make it black. Do you know any solution for that?

Here is a picture:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit


class SimplestCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

var sImageView: UIImageView!

override func awakeFromNib() {



    sImageView = UIImageView(frame: contentView.frame)
    sImageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    sImageView.clipsToBounds = true


    let sImage = UIImage(named: "banana.png")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    sImageView.image = sImage
    sImageView.tintColor = UIColor.orange

    contentView.addSubview(sImageView)

    }


}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate,     UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 49
}

// we use this method to dequeue the cell and set it up
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "sCell", for: indexPath) as! SimplestCollectionViewCell
    cell.awakeFromNib()
    return cell
}
```

}

Update: Compiler errors in the suggested code:
[image]

Comment: Do u want alternate background color cell?

Comment: No, I just want to change a color of banana in the second cell into black, for example.

Comment: Why not take a simple flag to decide if a cell needs to have background as black as no, set the flags value in your cellForItemAt indexPath.

Comment: Thanks, but I never seen it before, sorry. Could you give a sample how to make it?

Comment: @Roman sure I shall add an answer for the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import UIKit

class SimplestCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

var sImageView: UIImageView!
var shouldCellBeBlack: Bool = false//give any suitable name you like
override func awakeFromNib() {



sImageView = UIImageView(frame: contentView.frame)
sImageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
sImageView.clipsToBounds = true


let sImage = UIImage(named: "banana.png")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
sImageView.image = sImage

sImageView.tintColor  = shouldCellBeBlack ? UIColor.black :  UIColor.orange

contentView.addSubview(sImageView)

}


}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate,     UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 49
}

// we use this method to dequeue the cell and set it up
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "sCell", for: indexPath) as! SimplestCollectionViewCell
    if indexPath.row == 2 //set the value of the cell whose image you want to make black {
      cell.shouldCellBeBlack = true
    }else {
      cell.shouldCellBeBlack = false
    }
    cell.awakeFromNib()
    return cell
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but I got swift compiler errors in this line: shouldCellBeBlack ? sImageView.tintColor = UIColor.black : sImageView.tintColor = UIColor.orange and in this one:cell.shouldCellBeBlack = true/false Perhaps I should use a more simple symtax

Comment: true/false meant you can set either value as per your convenience 
I have updated my answer for the other error you are getting. Please check
I would appreciate it if you accept this as the right answer in case it worked for you, cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your efforts and time, but now I am getting the following result: all bananas are either orange or black. But what I need is something different: all bananas are orange and only one (for example, the second cell's banana) is black.

Comment: Thousand thanks, it works! I also found a solution using tags:     cell.sImageView.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.sImageView.viewWithTag(1)?.tintColor = UIColor.black